# Is it possible to access the launching shortcut directory from a Python executalbe?

Tags: python, windows, windows-installer, cx-freeze

I currently have a Python scrip that runs through all Excel files in the current directory and generates a PDF report.

It works fine now but I don't want the users to be anywhere near frozen Python scripts. I created an MSI with cxFreeze which puts the EXE and scripts in the *Program Files* directory.

What I would like to be able to do is create a shortcut to this executable and pass the directory the shortcut was run from to the Python program so that can be set as the working directory. This would allow the user to move the shortcut to any folder of Excel files and generate a report there.

Does Windows send the location of a opened shortcut to the executable and is there a way to access it from Python?

Comment: Do you want the working directory of the parent process that runs the .LNK shortcut? If so, leave the "start in" field blank to inherit that parent's working directory. I use this approach sometimes when running shortcuts from the command line. I have .LNK in `PATHEXT`, so I don't have to explicitly type the .lnk file extension.

Comment: But then you ask "[d]oes Windows send the location of a opened shortcut"? That's not the working directory. But you can get that information as well. Call [`GetStartupInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683230) to get the process startup info. If `dwFlags` includes `STARTF_TITLEISLINKNAME`, then the `lpTitle` field is the path to the .LNK shortcut file. Bear in mind your shortcut should directly run the executable of the process that calls `GetStartupInfo`. This may not be compatible with a frozen script if it unpacks and executes another program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you launch a shortcut, Windows changes the working directory to the directory specified in the shortcut, in the **Start in** field. At this point, Windows has no memory of where the shortcut was stored.

You could change the **Start in** field to point to the directory that the shortcut is in. But you'd have to do that for every single shortcut, and never make a mistake.

The better approach is to use a script, rather than a shortcut. Place your actual Python script (which we'll call `doit.py` for sake of example) somewhere in your `PYTHONPATH`. Then create a single-line Python script that imports it:

```
import doit
```

Save it (but don't name it `doit.py`) and copy it to each directory from which you want to be able to invoke the main script. In `doit.py` you can use `os.getcwd()` to find out what directory you're being invoked from.

You could also do it with a batch file. This is a little more flexible in that you can specify the exact name of the script and which Python interpreter should be used, and don't need to store the script in a directory in `PYTHONPATH`. Also, you don't need to worry about the file's name clashing with the name of a Python module. Simply put this line in a file:

```
C:\path\to\your\python.exe C:\path\to\your\script.py
```

Save it as (e.g.) `doit.bat` and copy it into the directories from which you want to invoke it. As before, your Python script can call `os.getcwd()` to get the directory. Or you can write it so your Python script accepts it as the first argument, and write your batch file like:

```
C:\path\to\your\python.exe C:\path\to\your\script.py %cd%
```

Another thing you can do with the batch file approach is add a `pause` command to the end so that the user is asked to press a key after the script runs, giving them the opportunity to read any output generated by the script. You could even make this conditional so that it only happens if an error occurs (which requires returning a proper exit code from the script). I'll leave that as an exercise.  :-)

Comment: The target machine will not have Python which is mostly why I'm using cxFreeze, to simplify things. Will this still work? I would need to pass a parameter to the exe right? I didn't think of the bat file, way better than a shortcut.

Comment: I'm not sure what effect freezing it would have on the working directory, but it's easy enough to check by freezing a script that just prints the working directory...

Comment: "At this point, Windows has no memory of where the shortcut was stored". No, it's the `lpTitle` field of the process startup info.

Comment: " In doit.py you can use `os.getcwd()` to find out what directory you're being invoked from". `os.getcwd()` has nothing to do with the location of the script. It's the current working directory of the Python process, which was either inherited from the parent process or explicitly set by the parent. When you run a file from an Explorer window, it changes the working directory to the file. If you run it from the Win+R dialog, the working directory is the user profile directory. In other contexts it's the System32 directory -- or pretty much anything depending on the parent.

Comment: The location of a batch script is `%~dp0` (i.e. the drive and path of argument 0).

Answer (score 0):

Is there a problem with modifying the script to take the directory to process as a command line argument?

You could then configure the different shortcuts to pass in the appropriate directory.

Answer (score 0):

Type the following into a batch file (i.e. `script.bat`):

```
python \absolute\path\to\your\script.py %~dp0
pause
```

Then add these imports at the top of your python file `script.py` (if not already included):

```
import os
import sys
```

And add this to the bottom of the python file (or combine it with a similar statement):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # set current working directory:
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        os.chdir(sys.argv[1])

    main()
```

replace `main()` with whatever function you want to call or code you want to run.

---

The following is how I came to my answer:

I tried using [kindall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48998679/12808884) and had the following issues:

- The first suggestion of storing the script somewhere in `PYTHONPATH` could not be applied to my situation because my script will be used on a server and needs to be independent of the client computer's python environment (besides having the required pip installations).
- I tried calling my python script from a Windows Batch File which could be moved to a different location.  Instead of the batch file's location being used as the current working directory, it was `C:\Windows`.
- I tried passing `%cd%` as an argument to my python script, then setting that to be my CWD.  This still resulted in a CWD of `C:\Windows`.

After reviewing the comments, I tried [Eryk Sun's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48998492#comment85066758_48998679) of instead passing `%~dp0` as an argument to the python script.  This resulted in the CWD being correctly set to the batch file's location.

I hope this helps others facing similar difficulties.